# Combine interfaces without defining a new one

Tags: go, syntax, interface

In go can you combine interface inline with a function signature or is that not possible and the only option is to create a third interface that combines the smaller ones?

```
// _Interfaces_ are named collections of method
// signatures.

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

// Here's a basic interface for geometric shapes.
type geometry interface {
    area() float64
    perim() float64
}

type appearance interface {
    color() string
    texture() string
}



// For our example we'll implement this interface on
// `rect` and `circle` types.
type rect struct {
    width, height float64
}
type circle struct {
    radius float64
}

// To implement an interface in Go, we just need to
// implement all the methods in the interface. Here we
// implement `geometry` on `rect`s.
func (r rect) area() float64 {
    return r.width * r.height
}
func (r rect) perim() float64 {
    return 2*r.width + 2*r.height
}

// The implementation for `circle`s.
func (c circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * c.radius * c.radius
}
func (c circle) perim() float64 {
    return 2 * math.Pi * c.radius
}

// can I combine interfaces in line here without creating a third interface that combines geometry and appearance.
func measure(g {geometry appearance}) {
    fmt.Println(g)
    fmt.Println(g.area())
    fmt.Println(g.perim())
    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Interfaces may embed other interfaces. So you may use an anonymous interface type that embeds `geometry` and `appearance` like this:

```
func measure(g interface {
    geometry
    appearance
}) {
    fmt.Println(g)
    fmt.Println(g.area())  // Method defined by geometry
    fmt.Println(g.perim()) // Method defined by geometry
    fmt.Println(g.color()) // Method defined by appearance
}
```

This is detailed in [Spec: Interface types:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> #### Embedded interfaces
>
> In a slightly more general form an interface `T` may use a (possibly qualified) interface type name `E` as an interface element. This is called *embedding* interface `E` in `T`. The type set of `T` is the *intersection* of the type sets defined by `T`'s explicitly declared methods and the type sets of `T`’s embedded interfaces. In other words, the type set of `T` is the set of all types that implement all the explicitly declared methods of `T` and also all the methods of `E`.